# How to get questions with specific tag on ManyToMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have these tables: `questions` for holding some questions, `tags` for holding tags and `question_tag` which looks like this:

[image]

In order to show all the tags, I added this:

```
@foreach(\App\Models\Tag::all() as $tag)
   <li><a href="tags/{{ $tag->name }}">{{ $tag->name }}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

Now I want to get all the questions that come with a specific tag. So I added this route:

Route::get('tags/{name}' , [HomeController::class, 'tag']);

But now unfortunately I don't know how what to add inside `tag()` method in order to get all the questions with this specific tag...

I have already added these relationships to Models:

`Tag.php`:

```
public function questions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class);
    }
```

`Question.php`:

```
public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
    }
```

So if you know how to get all question from specific tag, please let me know...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `foreach($tag->questions as $question)`... ? Also, can you elaborate more on your pivot table?

Comment: please show your controller also

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you looking for.

```php
public function tag()
{
    $questions = Question::whereHas(function ($tagQuery) {
        // Your query|condition in tag model.
        $tagQuery->where(/*Your condition*/);
    })->get();
    dd($questions->toArray());
}
```

Here is another way

```php
public function tag()
{
    $questions = Tag::where(/* Condition on tags */)->findOrFail($id)
        ->questions()
        ->where(/* Condition on questions */)
        ->get();

    dd($questions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use name conventions for controllers: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller
and route model binding https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding.

In `Tag` model:

```
/**
 * Get the route key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'name';
}
```

`$tag->name` must be unique and preferably like a slug. (tag-name-example)

In routes `web.php`:

```
Route::get('tags/{tag}/questions' , [QuestionController::class, 'index'])
   ->name('questions.index');
```

In `QuestionController` (like you `HomeController`)

```
public function index(Tag $tag)
{
    $questions = $tag->questions()->get();

    return view('questions.index', compact('questions'));
}
```